# fill not defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, liveedit

So I am making a number analyzer code in JavaScript and previously i was using  https://www.khanacademy.org
to write the code and run it in their live editor but that doesn't allow me to run `window.prompt`
so i shifted to some other editors but all of them are giving me an error when I try to fill something with color like this:

`fill (255, 0, 0);`

error: `JavaScript error: Uncaught ReferenceError: fill is not defined on line 3` why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Are you by any chance looking for `Array.fill`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: Can you share relevant code?

Comment: Probably more like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fill – you need to have a canvas rendering context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill` is an helper function that is only available in your course environment. `window.prompt` is probably disabled to avoid pranks that show thousand of dialogs lol